# Create a google password checkup process

Tags: java, spring, security

I need to create a workflow like google password checkup shows.
I wonder if exists a spring security branch or generally a java security framework that help me to reach this purpose. Hope this link can help me to explain better what I mean

[Google checkup password](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-launches-password-checkup-feature-will-add-it-to-chrome-later-this-year/)